# deep watch attribute passed to a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive to which I am passing an object that is dynamically built :

```
<my-directive passed-value="ctrl.buildValue()"></my-directive>

angular
.module('myModule')
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            passedValue: '='
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/my-directive.html',
        controller: function () {
            var that = this;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Suppose the object is always a new object but the object properties never change, for example :

```
myController.buildValue = function() {
    return {someValue: 'abcd'}
};
```

**Then angular enters into an infinite loop, because (I think) the object returned is always a new object.**

**So how can I ask angular to consider the object as not having changed if its properties are the same, even if the object is new ?**

It should be possible, because I know that when I deep watch an object (using `$watch(..., true)`), angular considers that the object is the same if its properties are the same, even if the object is always a new one.

Comment: The `$watch` as and optional parameter `objectEquality` which you can set to `true` and it uses `angular.equals` instead of reference, [$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). This might help you

Answer (score 0):

You'd better not use a method in an `passed-value` attribute, even though it returns an object. Because you defined that attribute as:

```
scope: {
    passedValue: '='
}
```

Which is expecting exactly an object.

The cause of your problem is that AngularJS refreshes the parts of page in every change. So, even if the method returns an object, it will run almost infinite times.

I recommend you binding an object variable to that attribute. For example, create a variable in your controller, initialize it via your method:

```
vm.myValue = vm.buildValue();
```

And then, pass this parameter to your directive:

```
<my-directive passed-value="ctrl.myValue"></my-directive>
```